# spring boot redirect to page login

Tags: spring, security

I have an application developped with spring boot and angularjs,
i'm using spring security for secured my app but 
i don't have any idea how redirect any member to page 
login if is not connected:
for example i have this rest api:

```
http://localhost:8080/user
```

but when i will consume this app the result is
[image]

how to redirect me to this page

```
http://localhost:8080/app/login
```

Comment: Check yours logs because you need to insert one password related with spring security, then you will be able to execute your rest api normally

Comment: thanks for your response,but my question is how to redirect me to http://localhost:8080/app/login if am not connecting

Comment: I told you that because i already got same problem with spring boot and security, then i had to setup the password from the logs, an auto generated password of 20-24 characters, then i was able to work normally with the app and will be redirect.

Comment: it's resolved using this solution:                                                            `@Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
   http.csrf().disable()
    .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login")).accessDeniedPage("/accessDenied")
     .and()
    .authorizeRequests()   .... `

Answer (score 0):

```java
private final RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new DefaultRedirectStrategy();
redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, "/login/");
```

Comment: Can you please also add explanation?

Comment: Spring security should throw an exception when an unauthorized user tries to get inside the application. When configuring, you need to set an exception handler to handle these exceptions:
```java
http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint((request, response, e) -> {
            if (request.getRequestURI().contains("api/")) {
                response.sendError(HttpStatus.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
            } else {
                redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, "/login/");
            }
        });
```